# How to use a ViewModelLocator in a user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, app.xaml, viewmodellocator

I was asked to convert a standalone WPF application that uses the MVVM pattern into a user control. This app consists of a main window and a few other windows. However, I get a few errors when trying to do so all pointing to my App.xaml class and other resources declared like converters:

`Library project file cannot specify ApplicationDefintion element.`
`The project file contains a property value that is not valid.`
`The name "ViewModelLocator" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MapperX.ViewModels"`.

So it looks like the errors revolve around my ViewModelLocator.

Currently the project directory structure is set up like so:

Top level -> ViewModels folder -> ViewModelLocator

The App.xaml is set up like so:

```
<Application x:Class="MapperX.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MapperX"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MapperX.ViewModels"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And here's a snippet of the `ViewModelLocator` class:

```
namespace MapperX.ViewModels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class instantiates all the viewmodels
    /// </summary>
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        WpfMap map = new WpfMap();

        private MainViewModel _mainViewModel;
        public MainViewModel MainViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                if (_mainViewModel == null)
                {
                    _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel(map)
                }
                return _mainViewModel;
            }
        }

        private LayersViewModel _layersViewModel;
        public LayersViewModel LayersViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                if (_layersViewModel == null)
                {
                    _layersViewModel = new LayersViewModel(map)
                }
                return _layersViewModel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then I set the `DataContext` for the views .xaml like so:
`DataContext="{Binding Path=MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"`

What's the correct way to still be able to use the ViewModelLocator without the App.xaml??

Comment: "Convert a WPF application into a user control"? This doesn't make much sense to me. There has to be an application somewhere. Are you trying to move the views to a separate project or what are you trying to do?

Comment: They want to be able to drop it into another application and create an instance of it to talk to it directly and/or create a wrapper around the whole project.

Comment: Basically they have a container in another application and want to fill it with this application's main window.

Comment: So you are creating a user control library to be consumed in an application?

Comment: Yup that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on a resource, you may create an attached property to set the `DataContext` of the views in your control library:

```
namespace ControlsAndResources
{
    public class View
    {
        private static readonly ViewModelLocator s_viewModelLocator = new ViewModelLocator();

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ViewModel", typeof(string), 
            typeof(ViewModelLocator), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnChanged)));

        public static void SetViewModel(UserControl view, string value) => view.SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);

        public static string GetViewModel(UserControl view) => (string)view.GetValue(ViewModelProperty);

        private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl view = (UserControl)d;
            string viewModel = e.NewValue as string;
            switch (viewModel)
            {
                case "MainViewModel":
                    view.DataContext = s_viewModelLocator.MainViewModel;
                    break;
                case "LayersViewModel":
                    view.DataContext = s_viewModelLocator.LayersViewModel;
                    break;
                default:
                    view.DataContext = null;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<UserControl xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlsAndResources" ... 
             local:View.ViewModel="MainViewModel">
```

Comment: I like this approach! for some reason though in the .xaml it's saying it doesn't exist in the namespace for this part: `local:View.ViewModel="MainViewModel`

Comment: Did you try to build? Make sure that the namespace of the `View` class is called "ControlsAndResources" or whatever you have mapped it to in your XAML.

Comment: So will this create a single viewmodel for each type of vm that I put in there that will stay alive for the duration of the usercontrol? I originally tried this but was told having static viewmodels goes against the MVVM pattern.

Comment: It uses the exact same `ViewModelLocator` class to get a view model and then it simply sets the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` to this view model. It's unclear what you mean by "static view models".

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the `ViewModelLocator` in your top-level `UserControl`?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: It seems to work for the main user control, but not for other views nested in a Views folder. Keeps saying the ViewModelLocator doesn't exist in the MapperX namespace, even though it's at the top most level.

Comment: if the items in the Views folder only get used within your main UserControl, then you do not need to set a DataContext as they'll inherit it from the UserControl instance

Comment: Sorry I explained it a bit wrong. I have other windows that are displayed within the project via showdialog(), and those had their datacontexts set via the ViewModelLocator as well. Those are in a 'Views' folder, while the main "view" is top most level and is the user control.