# MVVM Architecture for a large user control project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, architecture, user-controls

I was recently asked to convert a fairly large desktop application into a single control that can be added to other forms/windows. In the desktop version, it consists of a mainwindow which spawns other windows.

There is a ViewModelLocator class that initializes various objects and viewmodels for the windows and injects the proper objects into those viewmodels' constructors. Here's an example of what's in the ViewModelLocator and the MainWindow.xaml:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    CustomMap Map = new CustomMap();
    ObservableCollection<Styles> MapStyles = new ObservableCollection<Styles>();

    public MainViewModel MainViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mainViewModel == null)
            {
                _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel(Map, Styles);
            }
            return _mainViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how the mainwindow sets it's datacontext:

```
<Window x:Class="DesktopApp.MainWindow"
        DataContext="{Binding Path=MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
</Window>
```

And this is in the App.xaml to add the ViewModelLocator as a resource:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
</Application.Resources>
```

There are a few other viewmodels and windows set up the same way. They all share various objects that are initiated in the viewmodellocator by having the locator inject those objects into the constructors of the viewmodels.

The main problem is that when I convert this app to a usercontrol, I have to get rid of the App.xaml, which takes away the viewmodellocator as well unless I make everything in it static or make some singleton version of it.

What is the best way to initialize these viewmodels and share the data between them? Would I have to put everything in the MainWindow's (now a usercontrol) code behind since that is the entry point now?

I would love to keep this in line with the MVVM pattern as much as possible.

Comment: What is a "_usercontrol_" ? a separate .DLL ?

Comment: if just an actual `UserControl`, then you can just replace `Application.Resources` with `UserControl.Resources`

Comment: Have a look at existing MVVM frameworks, like Caliburn.Micro, MVVM light or MVVM cross. They have a lot of capabilities to create and bind view and viewmodels

Comment: Usercontrol in this case is a separate .dll yes. I converted the output of the project to a class library first. Was that the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: What's wrong with the approach I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129727/how-to-use-a-viewmodellocator-in-a-user-control/54130609#54130609)?